# How can i make windows media player control to be played in full screen?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, youtube, youtube-api

First i'm getting list of all my youtube videos and add the list to a listBox:

```
static List<string> videosList = new List<string>();
        static List<string> videosUrl = new List<string>();
        public async void RetrieveUploadsList()
        {
            UserCredentials();
            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
            });

            var channelsListRequest = youtubeService.Channels.List("contentDetails");
            channelsListRequest.Mine = true;

            var channelsListResponse = await channelsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

            foreach (var channel in channelsListResponse.Items)
            {
                var uploadsListId = channel.ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Uploads;

                Console.WriteLine("Videos in list {0}", uploadsListId);

                var nextPageToken = "";
                while (nextPageToken != null)
                {
                    var playlistItemsListRequest = youtubeService.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
                    playlistItemsListRequest.PlaylistId = uploadsListId;
                    playlistItemsListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
                    playlistItemsListRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;
                    var playlistItemsListResponse = await playlistItemsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

                    foreach (var playlistItem in playlistItemsListResponse.Items)
                    {
                            videosList.Add(playlistItem.Snippet.Title + "  " + playlistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId);
                            videosUrl.Add("http://www.youtube.com/v/" + playlistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId);
                            listBox1.Items.Add(playlistItem.Snippet.Title + "  " + playlistItem.Snippet.PublishedAt);    
                    }
                    nextPageToken = playlistItemsListResponse.NextPageToken;
                }
            }
            if (this.listBox1.Items.Count > 80)
            {
                this.listBox1.SelectedIndex = 80;
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = videosUrl[80];
            }
        }
```

Then listBox1 selected index changed event:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = videosUrl[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
        }
```

And last the windows media player control playstate change event:

```
private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
        {
            e.newState = 2;
            if (e.newState == 3)
            {
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.fullScreen = true;
            }
        }
```

The problem is that before i'm clicking anything to start playing any video from the list it's getting to the PlayStateChange event and trying to do the fullScreen = true seems like it's trying to start playing the video automatic.

So i added this:

```
e.newState = 2;
```

The code 2 mean pause. But now even if i will click the play button it will make this line e.newState = 2; and it will be paused.

I can't find a way to make it not to start playing it automatic or thinking it does.

You can see in this link all the codes for e.newState

[newState codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562460(v=vs.85).aspx)

Code 1 = stopped

Code 2 = paused

Code 3 = playing

Comment: I used the example in the link using the switch and case and it's working fine now.

Comment: **How can I make Windows Media Player control to be played in full screen?** You can handle `PlayStateChange` event and then check `if (this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying)
        {
            this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.fullScreen = true;
        }` This way, each time you play a video, it goes to fullscreen mode.